# Error when delete files using bat

Tags: batch-file

```
cd "D:\WWW\SEAP_P\Web\Sec.Seap.Application\prod\TSE\mailer_bin\sent"
echo y | del *.*
```

I want to delete all the files from sent directory,when i run the bat file.it delete all the file from my desktop.can i know what caused this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first please choose your destination drive then set directory you want to delete. here is looks like

```
D:
cd "WWW\SEAP_P\Web\Sec.Seap.Application\prod\TSE\mailer_bin\sent"
echo y | del *.*
```

make sure `D:` without `"`

or

```
cd /d "D:\WWW\SEAP_P\Web\Sec.Seap.Application\prod\TSE\mailer_bin\sent"
echo y | del *.*
```

as suggested by @SomethingDark in comment (Thanks BTW),

Let me know if it works.

Comment: You could also use `cd /d "D:\WWW\SEAP_P\Web\Sec.Seap.Application\prod\TSE\mailer_bin\sent"`

Comment: Certainly. OP needs to understand that each drive has its own "current directory", set by `cd d:\new\current\directory` (where `d:` is a drive letter) and if the drive letter is omitted, then the current directory is changed on the current **drive** `d:` changes the current **drive** `cd /d` changes **both**